# iPod will not play entire songs/albums

Tags: ipod, music

My 5th gen iPod classic and 1st gen iPod nano both skip two entire albums. The iPod automatically skips every song in the album. These albums both play fine in iTunes. Also, both albums played fine a few weeks ago. I have deleted and re-imported the albums into iTunes and the iPod many times. The ID3 tags and the format match the other songs in my iTunes, and I do not know what is causing this problem. What should I do?